# How to Get the Correct Time Format When the InTime and OutTime Reaches after 12AM in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tried to do punch in punch out time of the employees, I have tried the below query, it works fine when the punch in time is like 10:00am and punch out time like 6:00pm, and shows TotalDuration as 8hrs.

But it fails when the punch in time like 9:00pm and 5:00am.

About the problem, I have done calculation based on punch in and punch out which shows total hours.

But when the user punches after 12am it shows as 00:00 on both the punch in and punch out and TotalDuration as 0

The output that I get

```
    I:9:05AM\nO:5:32PM\nT:8:27 \nS :~Present On WeeklyOff - WeekOff,:Saturday,:    
    I:12:00AM\nO:12:00AM\nT:0:0  \nS :~Present On WeeklyOff - WeekOff,:Saturday,:
```

Here is my query :

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.EmployeeCode,AttendanceDate DESC) AS 'SNo',  
    e.EmployeeCode AS 'EmpID',  
    e.EmployeeName AS 'EmpName',  
    d.DepartmentFName AS 'DeptName', 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.AttendanceDate, 110) AS 'AttendanceDate',
    'I:' + LTRIM (RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),+'I:'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),+CONVERT(DATETIME, a.InTime,0)),100),7))+'\n'+'O:'+LTRIM (RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATETIME, CASE WHEN a.OutTime LIKE '%(%' THEN LEFT(a.OutTime, CHARINDEX('(', a.OutTime + ')') - 1)  
   ELSE a.OutTime END,0),100),7))+'\n'+ 'T:'+ CONVERT(CHAR(5),CAST(CAST(CASE WHEN  a.InTime> a.OutTime THEN DATEDIFF (MINUTE,CAST(a.InTime as datetime),DateAdd(day,1,CAST(a.OutTime AS datetime)))
 ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.InTime , a.OutTime) END AS INTEGER)/60 AS VARCHAR)+':'+CAST(cast(CASE WHEN  a.InTime> a.OutTime THEN DATEDIFF (MINUTE,CAST(a.InTime as datetime),DateAdd(day,1,CAST(a.OutTime AS datetime)))
 ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.InTime , a.OutTime) END AS INTEGER)%60 AS VARCHAR),108)+ '\n' + 'S :~' +  a.[Status]+ ' - ' + CASE WHEN a.[Status] = 'Present' THEN '' WHEN a.[Status] = 'On WeeklyOff' and la.LeaveType<>'' THEN la.LeaveType   
   WHEN DATENAME(dw, a.AttendanceDate)='Sunday' THEN 'WeekOff' WHEN DATENAME(dw, a.AttendanceDate)='SaturDay'   
   THEN 'WeekOff' ELSE la.LeaveType COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   ENd + ',:'+DATENAME(dw, a.AttendanceDate) + ',:'+ CASE WHEN la.LeaveStatus is null THEN '' ELSE la.LeaveStatus END AS 'PunchDetails',
   '0LOP' AS 'NoOfLOP',
   '0WkEnd' AS 'NoOfWkEndWorked' ,ISNULL(la.LeaveStatus,'') AS 'LeaveStatus' 

-- INTO #Result02  
FROM   
    esslsmartofficenew.dbo.Employees e (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN
    esslsmartofficenew.dbo.AttendanceLogs a (NOLOCK) ON e.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId 
INNER JOIN   
    esslsmartofficenew.dbo.Departments d (NOLOCK) ON d.DepartmentId = e.DepartmentId 
INNER JOIN  
    esslsmartofficenew.dbo.Shifts s (NOLOCK) ON s.ShiftId = a.ShiftId 
LEFT JOIN  
    IntranetReleaseNew.dbo.LeaveApplication la ON la.EmpId collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = e.employeecode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
                                               AND a.AttendanceDate >= la.leavefromdate 
                                               AND a.AttendanceDate <= la.leaveTodate  
WHERE   
    e.DepartmentId = '10' AND  
    e.EmployeeName NOT LIKE '%del_%' AND
    e.EmployeeCode LIKE '%S%' AND 
    e.EmployeeCode NOT LIKE '%Del_%' AND
    a.AttendanceDate = '2017-05-13'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to try and untangle your code, so I am just going to address the relevant calculations.

If we can assume that when the outtime is less than the intime, then the outtime occured the next day we can use something like this:

Note: I am using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to reduce repeating the code that converts the times to datetime with the above assumption, you could use a subquery/derived table to the same effect.

```
create table t (employeeid int, attendancedate date, intime time(0), outtime time(0));
insert into t values (1,'20170601','21:00:00','05:00:00'),(2,'20170603','05:00:00','21:00:00');

;with cte as (
select *
  , indatetime =dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,intime),convert(datetime2(0),attendancedate))
  , outdatetime=case when outtime > intime
      then dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,outtime),convert(datetime2(0),attendancedate))
      else dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,outtime),convert(datetime2(0),dateadd(day,1,attendancedate)))
      end
from t
)
select 
    employeeid
  , attendancedate
  , intime = ltrim(right(convert(varchar(23),convert(datetime,intime ),100),7))
  , outtime= ltrim(right(convert(varchar(23),convert(datetime,outtime),100),7))
  /* if less than 24 hours we can use this simpler version: */
  , TotalDuration24 = convert(time(0),dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,indatetime,outdatetime),0))
  /* if values greater than 24 hours we would use this version: */
  , TotalDuration = convert(varchar(10),
      convert(varchar(4),(datediff(minute,indatetime,outdatetime)/60),2)+':'
     +right('00'+convert(varchar(2),datediff(minute,indatetime,outdatetime)%60),2)
    )
from cte
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OQFS42186

returns:

```
+------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| employeeid | attendancedate | intime | outtime | TotalDuration24 | TotalDuration |
+------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
|          1 | 2017-06-01     | 9:00PM | 5:00AM  | 08:00:00        | 8:00          |
|          2 | 2017-06-03     | 5:00AM | 9:00PM  | 16:00:00        | 16:00         |
+------------+----------------+--------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi.It Works Fine on all the Days even on Weekends but on a single scenario it fails.It Fails When a person's intime is 6.00pm and outtime 4.00am(For Example).I mean if It passes 11.59pm on Saturday its intime and Outtime shows 12.00 and 12.00